# Will deployment to a physical Apple iPhone 8 work on XCODE 13 with Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am Completely new to the Apple / iOS development and unfamiliar with XCODE  . I know that Apple has announced that all apps must be done with XCODE 13 . Would i still be able to connect a iPhone 8 device as I am looking to buy device for Apple development using Flutter

Any advice would be much appreciated as I am completely unfamiliar with Xcode/Apple Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter uses Xcode tools to make iOS build, so it is connected to Apple's infrastructure. When you decide to build flutter app you will still need to install the latest Xcode [as you may see here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#ios-setup).

So to release iOS app you must build it for the latest supported version of iOS operating system. Therefore to test it you need a device which supports iOS 15

According to [release notes of Xcode 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes):

> Xcode 13 includes SDKs for iOS 15, iPadOS 15, tvOS 15, watchOS 8, and
> macOS Big Sur 11.3. The Xcode 13 release supports on-device debugging
> for iOS 9 and later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and later. Xcode
> 13 requires a Mac running macOS 11.3 or later.

You can see list of devices which receive the latest iOS updates [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/supported-models-iphe3fa5df43/ios)

In the long run its quite risky endeavour to buy the oldest device models from the list. (at the moment iPhone 8 not the oldest one with continuation support)

Comment: Thanks man . Yhea  ,  I just wanted to make sure if I purchase an i-phone that it wont have any issues